# Re-mounting Ubuntu from Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows

After restart my laptop I couldn't access the Ubuntu partition, simply I am directly adress to Windows without the possibility to choose between Ubuntu, Ubuntu Recovery Mode, Windows ....

From Windows I used DiskInternals Linux Reader and I can confirm that all my Ubuntu files are there. I attached pictures. [image: picture1][image: picture2] .

I red few links around such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20853/mount-ubuntus-partition-on-windows-7) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1066375/mount-ubuntu-partition-within-windows) but they did not help me.

So the question is, Can I re-mount Ubuntu FROM Windows to be able to access it again?

I have Window 10 Home 64bit.

Many thanks.

Comment: You want to boot into Ubuntu again or just access the data on the drive?

Comment: @ARG to boot into Ubuntu again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot the system into rescue mode, from your installation disc.

And then install grub.

```
update-grub
grub-install <device name of your ubuntu installation>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the boot loader needs to be fixed. You can use the boot-repair tool.

Boot from the live USB/CD and connect to the internet. Then type the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: The Ubuntu version in the live USB/CD must match the one I have installed? If so, how can I find it from Windows using DiskInternals Linux Reader? :o

Comment: No, it does not have to